# Parse and rename date in filename

Tags: shell, command-line, scripting

I have some files like this:

```
XXXXXXXX-15Jan2014.pdf
XXXXXXXX-15Jan2015.pdf
XXXXXXXX-22Aug2013.pdf
```

I'd like to rename them to

```
XXXXXXXX-2014-01-15.pdf
XXXXXXXX-2015-01-15.pdf
XXXXXXXX-2013-08-22.pdf
```

That is, rename `<day><month><year>` to `<year>-<month-as-number>-<day>`.

Is there a super easy linux/osx command to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I cant say about any command. 
Try this script.

```
 #!/bin/bash

for file in `ls`
do
        FirstPart=`echo $file|rev|cut -d"-" -f2|rev`
        MON=`echo $file|rev|cut -d"." -f2|rev`
        date=`echo $file|rev|cut -d"-" -f1|rev`
        read date year <<<${date//[^0-9]/ }
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "jan" && mon=1
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "feb" && mon=2
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "mar" && mon=3
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "apr" && mon=4
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "may" && mon=5
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "jun" && mon=6
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "jul" && mon=7
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "aug" && mon=8
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "sep" && mon=9
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "oct" && mon=10
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "nov" && mon=11
        echo "$MON" | grep -i "dec" && mon=12
        newName="$FirstPart-$year-$mon-$date"
        mv $file $newName
done
```

Answer (score 0):

awk can help:

```
awk -F'[-.]' '{c="date -d" $2 " +%F"; c|getline d;close(c);printf "mv %s %s-%s.pdf\n",$0,$1, d}'
```

the above one-liner will generate the `mv` command line to do the renaming. What you can try is:

```
ls -1 *.pdf|awk -F'[-.]' '{c="date -d" $2 " +%F"; c|getline d;close(c);printf "mv %s %s-%s.pdf\n",$0,$1, d}'
```

You will see the `mv ...` commands as output, to execute those statements to achieve your renaming goal, just pipe the command to `|sh`, that is:

```
ls ..|awk..|sh
```

I picked one of your file as example:

```
kent$  ls -1 *.pdf
XXXXXXXX-15Jan2014.pdf

kent$  ls -1 *.pdf|awk -F'[-.]' '{c="date -d" $2 " +%F"; c|getline d;close(c);printf "mv %s %s-%s.pdf\n",$0,$1, d}'|sh

kent$  ls -1 *.pdf                                                                                                    
XXXXXXXX-2014-01-15.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an OSX box to test on, but this should work:

```
while read filename; do 
    prefix=${filename%-*}
    ext=${filename##*.}
    date=${filename##*-}; date=${date%.*}
    echo mv "$filename" "$prefix-$(date -jf "%d%b%Y" "$date" "+%Y-%m-%d").$ext"
done <<END
XXXXXXXX-15Jan2014.pdf
XXXXXXXX-15Jan2015.pdf
XXXXXXXX-22Aug2013.pdf
END
```